# PDFBox File Size increasing after removing QR code also the process is too slow for large size pdf

Tags: java, optimization, pdfbox

I am currently using pdfbox 2.0.27 library for removing and adding the QR code image after loading the pdf file from the file system. Before removing the QR code image from the pdf file, the file size was 811 MB(10000 pages). After removing the QR code, the file size increases to 2.44 GB.

It was expected that after removing the QR code image, the file size should not increase, it should decrease or remain the same. Can you please help?

Also, it is taking too long to iterate all the pages Please suggest if any optimization is needed.

Below is the code for removing the Qr code :

```
pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(aBarcodeVO.getSourceFilePath()));
newDocument = new PDDocument();
Iterator<PDPage> pageIterator = pdDocument.getPages().iterator();

for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); pageCount++) {
    PDPage pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pageIterator.next());
    String imgUniqueId = aBarcodeVO.getImgUniqueId().concat(String.valueOf(pageCount));
    boolean hasQRCodeOnPage = removeQRCodeImage(newDocument, pdPage, imgUniqueId);
    qRCodePageList.add(hasQRCodeOnPage);
}
if(qRCodePageList.contains(true)) {
    newDocument.save(aBarcodeVO.getDestinationFilePath(true));
}
newDocument.close();
pdDocument.close();
```

remove QR code image from page code :

```
public static boolean removeQRCodeImage(PDDocument document, PDPage page, String imgUniqueId) throws Exception {
        String qrCodeCosName = null;
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        boolean hasQRCodeOnPage=false;
        for (COSName propertyName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {

            if (!pdResources.isImageXObject(propertyName)) {
                continue; 
            }
            PDXObject o;
            try {
                o = pdResources.getXObject(propertyName);
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    if (pdImageXObject.getMetadata() != null) {     
                        DomXmpParser xmpParser = new DomXmpParser();
                       XMPMetadata xmpMetadata = xmpParser.parse(pdImageXObject.getMetadata().toByteArray());
                     
                       if(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema()!=null && StringUtils.isNoneBlank(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle())&&xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle().contains("_barcodeimg_")) {
                            ((COSDictionary) pdResources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT))
                            .removeItem(propertyName);
                           log.debug("propertyName REMOVED--"+propertyName.getName());
                            qrCodeCosName = propertyName.getName();
                            hasQRCodeOnPage=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Exception in removeQRCodeImage() while extracting QR image:" + e, e);
            }
        }

        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
        log.debug("original tokens size" + tokens.size());
        List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object token = tokens.get(j);
            if (token instanceof Operator) {
                Operator op = (Operator) token;
                // find image - remove it
                if (op.getName().equals("Do")) {
                    COSName cosName = (COSName) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    if (cosName.getName().equals(qrCodeCosName)) {
                        newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            newTokens.add(token);
        }
        log.debug("tokens size" + newTokens.size());
        PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
        OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream();
        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
        out.close();
        page.setContents(newContents);
        return hasQRCodeOnPage;
    }
```

Comment: We don't know your input file, so we can only guess. My guess is that your input file uses object streams. PDFBox has been able to read object streams for quite a while, but support for writing them only starts with version 3 (current development target). The main advantage of the use of object streams is that they can be compressed. With your version 2.0.27, therefore, manipulated files are likely to grow in size.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for the response, can you suggest any optimization for the above code flow for removing the QR code?

Comment: Try whether the current development version of PDFBox solves the issue. If it does, upgrade your program to PDFBox 3 as soon as it is released.